# Как задать триггер на наличие элемента в коллекции?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Есть такой триггер:

```
<DataTrigger Binding ="{Binding SelectedGroup.Teeth[1].Name}" Value="Toggle16_down">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

То есть привязка к выбранной группе, а в группе есть еще свойство-список с некими элементами, и мне надо кнопку перекрасить в другой цвет если в этой выбранной группе, в свойстве (Teeth) есть элемент с именем "Toggle16_down". Если я вот так явно указываю индекс элемента, то код работает, но мне нужно проверить все элементы в коллекции и установить свойство при наличии хотя бы одного совпадения. Как это сделать?

Comment: Делайте в VM готовое отдельное свойство для этого

Comment: @АндрейNOP
Смотрите, чуть больше расскажу) у меня есть макет, с зубами нарисованными, я выделяю несколько зубов и формирую группу, которая попадает в Листбокс, и потом при наведении на эту группу в боксе нужные зубы(которые находятся в листе в группе) обретают другой цвет(есть 3 вида цвета). Я так понимаю, мне надо у группы выбранной сделать свойство, допустим цвет, и потом в триггере проверять сначала наличие зуба в списке, а потом смотреть цвет группы и красить зуб в этот цвет...я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, в группе отдельное свойство (но не цвет, конечно, а просто признак наличия нужного зуба) и заполнять его. Т.е wpf не умеет сам сканировать коллекцию и что-то в ней искать, вы должны сделать это в VM самостоятельно и выставить для предоставления свойство

Comment: @АндрейNOP
Понимаю о чем Вы, но совсем не понимаю как это реализовать в VM...это свойство должно быть у выбранной группы или в модели самого зуба?

Comment: У группы. У вас же есть отдельная VM для группы?

Comment: @АндрейNOP
У меня есть 2 модели: зуб и группа зубов(в ней есть свойство список зубов)

Comment: @АндрейNOP
И в VM я создал выбранную группу и коллекцию групп выходит

Comment: @АндрейNOP И дальше я в конструкторе сделал несколько групп, добавил их в листбокс и теперь мучаюсь как нужные зубы закрасить нужным цветом)

Comment: Группа может меняться после создания (добавляться/удаляться элементы)? Элемент может меняться после создания?

Comment: @АндрейNOP
группа не меняется, возможно только добавлять новую группу(еще не реализовал)
вы пишите надо создать переменную(bool) и как-то с ней работать чтобы узнать наличие элемента в группе?

Comment: Раз группа не меняется, то всё значительно упрощается. При создании группы просто устанавливайте это bool-свойство, а в представлении привязывайтесь к нему (можно даже сделать его вычисляемым, а не хранимым).

Comment: Проверьте, не исказил ли я смысл вопроса своей правкой (может я неправильно понял условие). Если всё так – напишу ответ.

Comment: @АндрейNOP
Изначально список групп пустой, я выбираю несколько зубов, картинки которых изображены на ToggleButton, ввожу название группы, выбираю цвет и нажимаю добавить, и она добавляется в ListBox. И когда я так просто ее выбираю нужные зубы(то есть ToggleBtn) приобретают цвет группы. С цветом я вроде разобрался, сделал привязку к этому свойству, а как сделать с зубами не пойму(

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код команды, которая создает группу из исходных данных: коллекции зубов, названия, цвета.

Comment: @АндрейNOP 
Еще не написал добавление, решил как-то пойти от конца и сначала сделать чтобы в цвет красились нужные зубы...сейчас попытаюсь сделать добавление группы через кнопку и сброшу код) если разберусь)